# 'MINMAXINFO' : undeclared identifier in MFC application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc

I tried to use MINMAXINFO to resize the window dynamically in MFC application (in VS 2008).
i added OnGetMinMaxInfo function through properties window.

When i compile the code, i get an error saying that

'ON_WM_GETMINMAXINFO': identifier not found
'MINMAXINFO' : undeclared identifier

Please help me to resolve this.

Regards,
AH

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have included afxcmn.h in your stdafx.h. This includes afxwin.h -> afx.h -> afxver_.h -> afxv_w32.h -> windows.h -> winuser.h -> MINMAXINFO.